# Soli Deo gloria: sol or solus?

Tags: ecclesiastical-latin, christianity, ambiguity

In the phrase *Soli Deo gloria* one can read *soli* in two different ways:

1. If it is *solus*, the phrase means "glory only to the God" or "glory to the only God".
2. If it is *sol*, the phrase means "glory to the Sun God".

In Christian context the first one is intended, of course.
But the second interpretation is also sensible.
The same happens whenever *solus Deus* is in dative, not only in this particular phrase.

When and how was this double meaning observed?
Are there examples from the pagan antiquity of the phrase *sol deus* in dative?

Comment: Perhaps you could find a Mithraic reference somewhere.

Comment: Note found in PHI at least: http://latin.packhum.org/concordance but why not…

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the Romans typically called their sun-god by the name of Deus Sol, not Sol Deus. Therefore I would not expect the Christian use of 'Soli Deo' to have been confusing or ambiguous to them.

- According to Manfred Clauss in *The Roman Cult of Mithras* (1990,
  translated 2001), [chapter 13](https://books.google.nl/books?id=Bh03DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA114-IA2), Mithraists referred to their
  sun-god as Deus Sol (not Sol Deus).
- Vicipaedia has a [picture](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sol_invictus#/media/Fasciculus:Elagabalus_Aureus_Sol_Invictus.png) of a coin with emperor Elagabalus on it, from the year 218, dedicated to DEO SOLI. Its [source](http://search.freefind.com/find.html?si=8253575&pid=r&n=0&_charset_=UTF-8&bcd=%C3%B7&query=%22deo+soli%22) has twelve
  other coins with Deo Soli, but none with Soli Deo.
- In *The Cult of Sol Invictus* (1972) by Gaston Halsberghe, Sol
  Deus, Soli Deo and Solis Dei are never used instead of
  Deus Sol, Deo Soli and Dei Solis. On [page 145](https://books.google.nl/books?id=d-l5DwAAQBAJ&pg=145),
  he writes that the Emperor Aurelian established a
  new office of 'Pontifex Dei Solis' around the year 280.
- The late fourth century *Res Gestae* of Ammianus Marcellinus, [chapter
  17](https://books.google.nl/books?id=ATtwRxzzAiYC&pg=RA1-PA110), has "deo Soli speciali munere dedicatus" (in Yonge's 1911
  [translation](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/28587/28587-h/28587-h.htm): "especially dedicated to the Sun-god").
- A few pages [later](https://books.google.nl/books?id=ATtwRxzzAiYC&pg=RA1-PA112), Ammianus translates one Hermapion's
  interpretation of the hieroglyphs on one of the obelisks in Rome. It
  contains both "Sol Deus magnus" (!, for " Ἥλιος θεὸς μέγας", Yonge:
  "The Sun, the great God") and "Deus Sol" (for " Ἥλιος θεὸς", Yonge: "the
  Sun, the god").
- Vicipaedia [uses](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deus_solis) 'deus solis' as a common term to refer to
  the sun-gods of various nations.

So I can find 'Sol Deus' only once, in a translation from Greek Ἥλιος θεὸς, which itself is claimed to be a translation from Egyptian.